# Get the value of element using javascript by its class name

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

hi everyone I have an element like this :

```
<div class="price-box">
     <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-27">
        <span class="price">
           ...
        </span>
      </span>

 </div>

<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" />
```

i have tried to get the value using this line

```
document.getElementByClassName('input-text qty').value="myvalue"
```

but that didn't work

how can I get the value without jquery?
note : I've included prototype.js in my project !

what about this one too :

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

I want to disable it using Javascript and by its class name !!!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be looking for [`querySelector`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors_api/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector( ".input-text.qty" );
```

This returns a single item, rather than a NodeList. If you would like a NodeList instead, use the alternative [`querySelectorAll`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors_api/querySelectorAll). Keep in mind that these methods take [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pattern-matching). The selectors you can use are limited to the browser this code is executed in. Keep it simple.

These two methods have better browser support than `getElementsByClassName`, so I would encourage you to use them instead of taking your current approach.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: i used it and in console it says TypeError: Qty is null

Comment: @Souf It works: http://jsfiddle.net/w9XN7/4/. Make sure that your selector is written properly.

Comment: var addToCartButton = document.querySelector(".button .btn-cart");

Comment: @Souf Don't add a space; in CSS selectors the space means `.btn-cart` is *inside* `.button`. If the two are both on the same element, you remove the space and make it `.button.btn-cart`.

Comment: setAtrribute worked but when i one enable it again it stays disable ??

Comment: @Souf Not sure I understand; you can `.removeAttribute( "disabled" )` to removed the boolean `disabled` attribute from the element. Alternatively, you could set the property to false too: `found[0].disabled = false` and that will re-enable it too.

Comment: I'm more curious about the animation demonstration playing out here then of the question itself!

Comment: wow, that gif was like a boss, I'm so dumb, I didn't know I could program using the console, that should be obvious to me xD

Comment: @Sampson really very nice article. Big appreciate. also very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Prototype in the page already, you may find this element using the "double-dollar" method:

```
$$('.input-text.qty');
```

As others have pointed out above, this returns an array of matched elements (or an empty array, if you don't have anything on the page that matches). So the easiest way to do anything  to the result is with invoke():

```
$$('.input-text.qty').invoke('setValue', 'myvalue');
```

or

```
$$('.input-text.qty').invoke('disable');
```

Any of the Prototype Element methods can be invoked in this manner. If you want to do something custom to the element(s) based on some attribute, you can use each() instead:

```
$$('.input-text.qty').each(function(elm){
  if (elm.frobber == 'froom') elm.remove();
});
```

Comment: the OP needs to get the value, hence doing `$$('.input-text.qty')[0].value` would get that - but +1 for extra `$$()` info

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, its `getElementsByClassName` (`elements` is plural) -- this will return an array of elements that satisfy the condition. You must specify the index of the array to modify the element properties:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input-text qty')[0].value="myvalue"
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByClassName()` returns the array of matched elements, so to acces the first element of array use `0` index like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input-text qty')[0].value="myvalue";
```

**Or**

You can use the id(**qty**) from input tag, and put the value on this tag by `getElementById()` something like

```
<input  type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" />

document.getElementById('qty').value="myvalue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `id="qty"` so forget `class`, just use

```
document.getElementById('qty').value = "myvalue";
```

Which is most efficient.

Other dom native methods like `getElementsByClassName/TagName`(*note there are `s` after Element*) returns an array like object `NodeList`.

You need to use index or loop to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You error is that you using:

1) `getElementByClassName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

2) `getElementsByClassName` returns array so you must get [0] element

So try this one:

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('input-text qty')
console.log(p[0])
p[0].value = "MyValue"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AaakJ/)